# java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Provider SunJCE does not provide DES/ECB/NoPadding

Tags: java, android, encryption, jpos

I am trying to decrypt data using org.jpos JCEHandler in Android like below code

```
public static byte[] decrypt(byte[] data, byte[] key, String algorithm) throws JCEHandlerException
{
    byte[] plainText;
    JCEHandler handler = new JCEHandler("com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE");
    SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, algorithm);
    plainText = handler.decryptData(data, secretKeySpec);
    return plainText;
}
```

but it catch Exception says Provider SunJCE does not provide `DES/ECB/NoPadding`

I call this function like below code

```
byteKey=Hex.decodeHex("abcdef0123456789".toCharArray());
Log.d("aabb","byteKey:"+byteKey);
TMK = Hex.decodeHex("abcdef0123456789".toCharArray());
byteKey = Crypto.decrypt(byteKey,TMK,"DES");
```

the log of byteKey is : `[B@1cbe2358`

what should I do , I try a lot  to solve it but always same error , can I find some codes do the same result of **handler.decryptData** in android can I find any help please ...

Comment: better use  "AES" rather then "DES"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
JCEHandler handler = new JCEHandler("com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE");
```

You are enforcing JCE provider to use `SunJCE` which may not have the corresponding crypto implementation for `DES/ECB/NoPadding`, you can either try other algo or use [**SpongyCastle**](https://rtyley.github.io/spongycastle/) as your security provider.

**Update:** **ECB** mode is already proved to be weak, you **should NOT use ECB** mode.

Comment: ok , thank's its totally clear , I will try SpongyCastls , If I face any problem I will feed you back ..